activeadmin_addons assets are not align to the activeadmin theme

Issue in activeadmin_addons tags input, slim select.
I am trying to align the form with adding the css inside the below path app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin.scss
no table to overide
tried to add the assets as per the developer inspect from developer tool

I would recommend posting the actual code used to generate this as well as the relevant html that is generated. A screen shot and tried does not provide sufficient context to assist in this case.
